# Count number of persons in both groups

Tags: mysql, sql

I have data as follows:

```
Person  |  Group
-----------------
Andy    |  1
Andy    |  2
Doug    |  2
Jack    |  1
Carl    |  2
Joe     |  1
Joe     |  2
```

I need an output from this data as follows:

```
num_persons  |  num_persons_in_both_groups  |  overlap
--------------------------------------------------------
5            |  2                           |  40%
```

I can get the `num_persons` but am confounded by `num_persons_in_both_groups`. How can I get this using SQL? Assuming it's MySQL. `overlap` is straightforward.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Great question! Try the below:

```
SELECT SUM(GroupCount) AS num_persons
    , SUM(CASE WHEN PersonsInGroups > 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS num_persons_in_both_groups
    , (SUM(CASE WHEN PersonsInGroups > 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / SUM(GroupCount))*100 AS overlap
FROM
(
SELECT COUNT(1) AS PersonsInGroups
    , 1 AS GroupCount
FROM t
GROUP BY Person
) x
```

Per the comment, you could actually just write it like:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) AS num_persons
    , SUM(CASE WHEN PersonsInGroups > 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS num_persons_in_both_groups
    , (SUM(CASE WHEN PersonsInGroups > 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / COUNT(1))*100 AS overlap
FROM
(
SELECT COUNT(1) AS PersonsInGroups
FROM t
GROUP BY Person
) x
```

Comment: Beautiful! Looks like it's working! I think the only change would be instead of `SUM(GroupCount)` it would be `COUNT(GroupCount)`? Since `GroupCount` is a string value?

Comment: Oh actually you don't even need group count... You could just use COUNT(1).. I'll update

Comment: Ah you're right, Its grouped by the person already in the nested query.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend two levels of aggregation:

```
select count(*) as num_persons,
       sum(group_1 > 0 and group_2 > 0) as in_both,
       avg(group_1 > 0 and group_2 > 0) as ratio
from (select person,
             max( group = 1 ) as group_1,
             max( group = 2 ) as group_2
      from t
      group by person
     ) p
```

I like this because it is flexible.

However, you can also do this without a subquery, assuming exactly two groups:

```
select count(distinct person) as num_persons,
       count(*) - count(distinct person) as num_in_both,
       (count(*) - count(distinct person)) / count(distinct person) as ratio
from t;
```

Comment: Your second query works like magic! So simple and yet so elegant! In the first query, what does `max(group = 1)` do?

Comment: @PlastyGrove . . . It returns "1" if `group = 1` for a given `person` and `0` otherwise.

Comment: Beautiful, very nice way to use `max` function. Thanks for explaining!